# Use array instead of array of parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to use the scissors module to join pdfs...

I have a variable number of files to merge so the code looks like:

```
var files = [scissors("a.pdf"), scissors("b.pdf")];
scissors.join( *** ).deflate().pdfStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(output));
```

Scissors expect one parameter for each file:

```
scissors.join(scissors("a.pdf"), scissors("b.pdf"), etc
```

so how can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
scissors.join.apply(scissors, files).deflate().pdfStream().pipe(stream);
```